# JSON decode with php include

Tags: php, include, json

I want to include a php file in one another and decode the JSON that I get.

Here´s my code:

```
<?php 

$jsonstring = include('php/get_recipe_byID.php');


$obj = json_decode($jsonstring);
print_r($obj->Data);

?>
```

`$jsonstring` is

```
{"Data":{"Recipes":{"Recipe_10":{"ID":"10","TITLE":"Pferde\u00e4pfel","TEXT":"Sammeln und Essen","COUNT_PERSONS":"4","DURATION":"60","USER_ID":"1","DATE":"1000-01-01 00:00:00"}}},"Message":null,"Code":200}
```

The error I get is

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /var/www/recipe_search.php on line 118
```

which is the row with     `print_r($obj->Data);`

How can I handle that?

Comment: Just try `print_r(json_decode($jsonstring));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you include the file and not use the file directly. You should be using [file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents) instead.

However!

I have some times had issues with using [json_decode](http://dk.php.net/json_decode) and its turning into objects, and i prefer using its associative array options instead. Try using

```
$obj = json_decode($jsonstring);
print_r($obj['Data']);
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means that `$obj` is not an object, and is probably null, because `$jsonstring` isn't a valid json string.

try to make a var_dump of $jsonstring and verify that at the end of your file php/get_recipe_byID.php you do a return.